# Calling a PHP variable in a JSON script - DudaMobile API White Label Self Service Solution

Tags: php, json, syntax

I am trying to implement the DudaMobile API White Label Self Service Solution found here: https://support.dudamobile.com/API/API-Use-Cases/White-Label-Self-Service

I have a form that the user fills out for first and last name, email and site address they want to import into the mobile builder.

Form code:

```
<form action="mobile.php" method="post">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Existing Website URL to Import <input type="text" name="site"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP Code getting the POST values into variables:

```
// Here you should define the sub account name, the first name and the last name
$accountName = $_POST["email"];
$firstName = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastname"];
$site = $_POST["site"];
```

The API works up until Step 2 where it attempts to call the site URL from the $site variable or the post data $_POST["site"].

```
// define the site url you would like to provide. We are using moeplumbing.com as an example here
$data = '
    {   
    "site_data":
        {               
            "original_site_url":"{original_site_url}"
        }
    }
';
```

I've tried replacing `{original_site_url}` with `$site`, `"site"` or `$_POST["site"]` and every combination of different quotes, dots and brackets, and I either get a syntax error, Unrecognized Token error or No Such URL error.  I've even tried an array instead with no luck.

What is the correct syntax to give a `original_site_url` a value of the `$site` variable?

Comment: Just noticed you were using surrounding single quotes; variables' values wont be shown within single quotes, ie: `$x_value=4; $data = 'x=$x_value'; echo $data;` will output `x=$x_value` instead of `x=4`. However, you could also keep the single quotes usage and utilize the `str_replace()` method.

Comment: Everything is double quoted, not sure what you are talking about here.

Comment: I see a single quote where you begin code with `$data = '` following the comment `// define the site...`

Comment: that's because it's JSON.  See my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  The correct format for JSON calling a variable is this:

```
"original_site_url":"'.$site.'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also escape the double quotes in the JSON so that you can reference the variables inline:

```
// define the site url you would like to provide. We are using moeplumbing.com as an example here
$data = "
{   
\"site_data\":
    {               
        \"original_site_url\":\"$site\"
    }
}
";
```